# Mono.Posix PInvoke has unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, mono, internationalization, gettext, xgettext

Only headaches from this Mono library...
I created simple C# console app from [this internationalization tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/i18ngettext/)
It works when building it with mono, but I want to build/run it using Visual Studio. I added `Mono.Posix` nuget to project.

Program looks like this:

```
using System;
using Mono.Unix;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

    public class i18n
    {
        public static void Main(string[] argv)
        {
            Catalog.Init("lv", "./locale");
            Console.WriteLine(Catalog.GetString("My name is {0}"), "Enzo");
            int i = 20;
            Console.WriteLine(Catalog.GetPluralString("I'm {0} year old.", "I'm {0} years old.", i), i);
            i = 21;
            Console.WriteLine(Catalog.GetPluralString("I'm {0} year old.", "I'm {0} years old.", i), i);
            i = 22;
            Console.WriteLine(Catalog.GetPluralString("I'm {0} year old.", "I'm {0} years old.", i), i);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

First I got error that `MonoPosixHelper.dll` could not be found. Added it. Then `intl.dll` was missing. Added. Now I get `PInvokeStackImbalance occured` message:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'D:\TESTS\i18n\i18n\bin\x86\Debug\i18n.vshost.exe'.
>
> Additional information: A call to PInvoke function 'Mono.Posix!Mono.Unix.Catalog::bindtextdomain' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

It all happens in `Catalog.Init("lv", "./locale");`
I have no clue what is wrong/missing etc.

Comment: "supported by Microsoft"??  No.  The last checkin for Catalog.cs was 3 years ago and annotates "Fix INTL.DLL CallingConvention".  Quite a coincidence, getting the calling convention wrong produces this error.  Crystal ball says that you copied the wrong intl.dll

Comment: My bad, misread "sponsored". Could you link to this checkin? I can't find it. I copied intl.dll from Mono directory in program files which I had freshly installed.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Posix/Mono.Unix